# Selenium2 profile to accept untrusted certificates

Tags: java, firefox, profile, certificate, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use a firefox profile with selenium2 to accept untrusted certificates, but without any success.  I'm using 2.0a5 of the selenium jar.  If I start firefox with the profile manager manually and navigate to the site then there is no challenge from the browser, however in selenium I cannot avoid it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the existing profile to be used by `FirefoxDriver` by setting the system property:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile", <Your profile here>);
```

Comment: How is System.setProperty different from driver.SetPreference?  This is an "about:config" preference right?